Exterior surface mount PVC box with 3/4" input coming straight from the wall into the box
I would like to put a surface mounted PVC box on a stucco wall and come with a 3/4" PVC conduit straight into the back of the box. Surprisingly, this doesn't seem to be as straight forward as I thought:

Most boxes (e.g. Carlon) have openings on the side. Some have openings on the back but mostly 1/2"
Openings are "threaded" but I was expecting to cement the PVC pipe into the box.

I would want to avoid additional bends, elbows, LLs/LRs because that area of the wall is already very crowded (under my deck).

There are surface mount boxes with 3/4 inch holes including rear ones.  You may be right that there are no PVC ones like that. I couldn't find one in my 15 seconds of online searching. :)   Is PVC critical for some reason?
If you want to use glued PVC you use a suitably sized (3/4 inch) threaded to PVC hub adapter.  You can screw one on to the back of a box, but you'll have to make an oversized hole in the wall to accommodate the hub.

I have found a metal box with 3/4" on the read but it has threads and doesn't fit my 3/4" PVC pipe. Also, I'm not sure if it's allowed to put PVC conduit into a metal box? Would you mind adding the reference to the box?

Yes you can attach electrical PVC to a metal outdoor rated box. You need a (3/4  male thread to 3/4 slip)   adapter. Thread the adapter into the box. Glue the pipe into the adapter.  Your hole needs to be big enough for the exterior diameter of the adapter.
